# topLayoutGuide.lenght is different in iOS7 and iOS8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, autolayout

I use a UIViewController inside a UINavigationcontroller.

To test the topLayoutGuide I did:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

   println("self.topLayoutGuide: \(self.topLayoutGuide.length)")

}
```

The result in iOS7 is:

```
self.topLayoutGuide: 20.0
```

The result in iOS8 is:

```
self.topLayoutGuide: 64.0
```

**Why is there a different value for the layout guides in iOS7 and iOS8? How do I get the same result for both iOS versions?**

Comment: my suggestion would be forget about iOS7, iOS9 is coming. Plus, most of people moved to iOS8 already.

Comment: Still 16% use iOS7 so I cannot forget it.